# (New to C++) Save a function pointer that can be called later

Tags: c++, templates

I've spent some time trying figure out how to do this but I think I need help. If I could use templates I can avoid having to type the function, like 'B::theFuncToBeCalled', right? But that only works if it's a static method, if I'm not mistaken?

```
// A.h
typedef std::function <void()> CbType;

class A
{
    template<typename T>
        void setCallback(T &cb);

    private:
        template <typename T>
        T callThisLater;
};

// A.cpp
template<typename T>
void A::setCallback(T &cb)
{
    this->callThisLater = cb;

    // later...

   ((CbType*)callThisLater)();
}

// B.cpp
// in constructor or wherever
{
    A* a;
    a->setCallback(this->theFuncToBeCalled);

    // or, anonymous
    CbType func = [this](){
        // do something
        // call theFuncToBeCalled() if I feel like it :)
    };

    a->setCallback(func);
}

void B::theFuncToBeCalled()
{
    log("yay");
}
```

(If I try doing it the anonymous way I get an access violation error.)

Comment: You could just save `std::function` in your class instead.

Comment: What is `((CbType*)callThisLater)();` supposed to do?

Comment: Never cast a function. If you get a type error, you're doing something wrong. Don't add a cast to silence the compiler.

Comment: Since the type of callThisLater is unknown until it is used, I cast it to be a CbType

Comment: @xerosugar That's one example of doing something wrong. If it's not actually a `CbType`, calling it as a `CbType` is undefined.

Comment: @xerosugar That's not how casting works. You're claiming that `callThisLater` *is* a pointer to `std::function<void()>` with this cast, which is almost certainly not true. If you want a `std::function<void(void)` there, store it as that in the first place.

Comment: I'm not even sure how `template <typename T> T callThisLater;` compiles in the first place. What you should do is to declare it as `CbType callThisLater;`. And also use `CbType` as the parameter for `setCallback`. No templates needed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat C++14 added variable templates

Comment: @Cubic Yes, but they can't be nonstatic member variables.

Comment: If I try to use function<void()> as parameter type then do a->setCallback(theFuncToBeCalled); then it says the params are incompatible because the func I try to pass belongs to a class "void (B::theFuncToBeCalled*)()". That's what I was hoping the templates would solve for me.

Comment: The compiler refuses to do that, because when you'll try to call the callback, how will it tell *on which instance* to call it? Passing lambda that captures `this` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is much wrong here. Let's discuss that and then how to fix it:

1. You cannot simply define templatized functions in the implementation file: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl
2. [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)'s [variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) are only available for static variables:

> A variable template defines a family of variables or static data members

3. You are passing a method, and trying to use it as though you passed a function, [methods implicitly take the `this` parameter](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#addr-of-memfn)
4. Once the type of `callThisLater` is defined to accept a method, it cannot be subsequently changed to accept a lambda with a different signature
5. `class A` is a poor re-implementation of what could be solved with a functor or even just a function pointer

Please simply eliminate `class A` and use a function pointer and a closure type:

```
auto a = &B::theFuncToBeCalled;
auto func = [=]() { (*this.*a)(); }
```

Rather than using `a` going forward simply use `func`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change my approach and instead of saving a pointer to a callback, I'm saving a pointer to the object the member function belongs to. It's the same amount of work, but with the benefit that if I ever need to call several different member functions, I can just do:

```
objRef->theFuncToBeCalled();

// later
objRef->theOtherFuncToBeCalled();
```

and all I need for this, is one pointer. Simple is Best™, amiright? :) Thanks for your help!